# Redirect stdout into buffer editor before piping to other commands

Tags: bash, nano

I'm trying to clean up my local set of git branches. There are quite a few, and I don't want to do `git branch -D branchname` for all of them. There's also no pattern that captures all and only the ones I want to kill. Then I remembered that I once saw someone pipe stdout into a buffer editor, and I thought that sounded perfect.

I'd like to take the output of `git branch -l`, pipe it into nano, edit the buffer, then (upon exiting nano) have the final buffer be supplied as the input into another command (specifically, `xargs git branch -D`).

Having played around for a while without luck, this has become an academic question related to editing buffers on the fly -- so, **no git-specific solutions, please**. I want to know how to edit buffers on the fly in bash one-liners, because it seems like the kind of bash-fu that could elevate me to godhood. Acceptable answers should also work when sandwiched between e.g. `find` and file or path operations (like `rm`, `cat`, or `grep`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semi-colon is a perfectly acceptable operator.

```
git branch -l > /tmp/branches; nano /tmp/branches; whatever /tmp/branches; rm /tmp/branches
```

Comment: This worked: `git branch -l > /tmp/branches; nano /tmp/branches; cat /tmp/branches | xargs git branch -D; rm /tmp/branches`; I'm still hoping to find a version that doesn't create files that need to be cleaned-up, but if nothing is forthcoming I'll mark this as an answer. Thanks!